# Kohana 3: Auth::factory() gives error

Tags: kohana-3, kohana-auth

When I try to make a new instance of the Auth-module object (Auth::factory()), Kohana gives me the following error:

> Cannot instantiate abstract class Auth

Can someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Auth::instance()` instead. It will create an Auth object with driver (ORM, File).